# Urbanairship - In-App message customization

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I already know that we have a configuration section in UrbanAirship site (Configuration -> In-App Messages) and read http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html#custom-style. But with this I can't change all the In-App layout.

In Sum:

1. **How I can change the style for button** (apply border, changing
   background color just for the button, color to the text button ...)?

   *Base.Widget.UrbanAirship.InAppMessage.Banner.ActionButton*
2. **How I can hide the divider between the button and notification description?**

   *Base.Widget.UrbanAirship.InAppMessage.Banner.Divider*

Answer (score 2):

Layout adjustments take a little bit more work but can be done. First you will need to create a custom InAppMessageFragment:

```
public class CustomInAppMessageFragment extends InAppMessageFragment {  
    @Override  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        if (getMessage() == null || getMessage().getAlert() == null) {  
            dismiss(false);  
            return null;  
        }  


        // Bind the in-app message to the layout. The fragment is attached to the content of the activity,  
        // so it has the full activity width and height to work with.  
        TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, container, false);  
        view.setText(getMessage().getAlert());  


        return view;  
    }  
}
```

Then set the fragment factory on the in-app message manager after takeOff:

```
airship.getInAppMessageManager().setFragmentFactory(new InAppMessageFragmentFactory() {  
    @Override  
    public InAppMessageFragment createFragment(InAppMessage message) {  
        return new CustomInAppMessageFragment();  
    }  
});
```

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/urbanairship-sdk/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/push/iam/InAppMessageFragment.java#L193) to see how the in-app message fragment's view is normally created.